# Is it possible to know the reason behind the asyncio.CancelledError in exception message itself?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I always want to know reason behind the exception - asyncio.CancelledError
I am using this for pyVim.connect.SmartConnect, but it gives exception asyncio.CancelledError for:
1.Wrong username/password
2.Host other than vcenter

I just want to know whether exception occurred for case 1 or case 2, Is there any such way??

Comment: `CancelledError` is normally raised when a task is canceled, and reason for canceling must be provided separately. There is no additional information in the exception itself.

Comment: Do you talk about [pyvmomi](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi)? It doesn't seem it supports `asyncio` at all, take a look at [examples here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/102579/pyVim.connect.SmartConnect).

Comment: Then which should I use, I want to catch for case 1 and case 2 as mentioned above, I need to show different messages for both cases